# Get text exactly from td using jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm able to get the row by using td text using "contains", but it fails if it has the text in td > span text.. Here is my scenario

```
<table id="tblAllMessages">
<tr><td>100</td><td><span>hi</span></td></tr>
<tr><td>200</td><td><span>100</span></td></tr>
</table>
```

if I use

```
$('#tblAllMessages td:contains('100')').parent("tr")
```

it will give me two rows.. But, I need only first row. It should not check 100 in second row, because its under span of a td..

Do I need to add anything else?

Comment: can't you just use first-child?

Comment: No. Because I don't know when I can add one more td later. So, I don't want to test it as statically.

Comment: ah i see how you mean now

Comment: @EddSmith, I need to check and find the only td text.. I need to check right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

(prettified version)

`$('#tblAllMessages  td')
          .filter(function ()
                        {
                         return $("<div/>").text($(this).html()).html()=='100'
                        })
          .closest("tr").css('background-color','red')`

http://jsbin.com/wizacahi/2/edit

[image]

The trick I used is  not to find any html entities inside it. ( but PURE text)

Comment: Thanks :) But, I've my text in the 6th td of my row.

Comment: Thank you. I've customized it to my requirement. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `:first` like below :

```
$('#tblAllMessages tr td:nth-child(6):contains("100"):not(:has(span)):first').closest('tr')
```

Working [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NLT8p/301/)

For More information on `:first` please see [:First API Doc](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/)

Comment: You said about first.. If the td is in middle or something?

Comment: Can you tell me, why did you use first?

Comment: @NizamAli the first here is not a safe solution.

Comment: @NizamAli, coz you ask ..But, I need only first row

Comment: @RoyiNamir, can you please explain why first is not safe?

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar Dont teach me about jquery selectors please. see for yourself why your solution doesnt work   ( when line are ordered differently) http://i.stack.imgur.com/SviKs.jpg

Comment: Guys! Please don't argue. I appreciate both answers.

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar, Still I'm not able to get it. Because I need to check the 6th td in my actual code. I've just posted a snippet in stack. Can you let me know? I'm trying as td:eq(6):contains('100')

Comment: @NizamAli, ok let me see the post.

Comment: @NizamAli, so you want to check only 6th td which has 100 but not ins span, right?

Answer (score 0):

try this,this will work

```
$(document).ready(function(){




        var $pressTitle =$('#tblAllMessages').find('td:first');

        var pressTitle=$pressTitle.next().text(); 

       alert(pressTitle);  



    }); 
 </script>
```

Comment: OP doesn't want just the first result if the table becomes dynamic/has more rows